# How to change content of a Tab while switching

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I am following one book tutorial. While developing it, I come across a typical problem. I need to know that how should I change my content of a Tab while I move from one tab to another? thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a nice tutorial of TabActivity you are looking for,

[Tab Example](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-tabhost-tutorial-part-1)

For changing the icon of selected tab you have to create an xml for each tab like this in drawable folder

**first_tab.xml**

```
    <item android:state_selected="false"        
          android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_icon"/>
    <item android:state_selected="true"        
          android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_icon"/>
</selector>
```

And the while creating tabs you have to use this xml like this,

```
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Activity_name.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("yourTab_name").setIndicator("yourTab_name",res.getDrawable(R.drawable. first_tab)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

And you are done with it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the link. But I need one more thing about it, and that is when I switch from one tab to another, the icon on the tab should also be changed accordingly, i.e. in the current tab the icon should be active and the tab in the background, the icon on the tab should be in inactive state. Any guess about it?