# Android - Create a tab bar

Tags: java, android

I am developing the Tab bar having two tabs in an activity. Problem here is unable to create the tab using the two images(for a single tab that is one left image and other is right image)in a tab bar. While clicking on the specific tab, only one image is focusing and the other is in a non responsive state. Is there any problem in android for creating the tabs using two images for a single tab? Please suggest me the answer with a sample code.

Comment: Well, checkout my this answer for changing the icon on selection, [Tab Selection icon changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226268/how-to-change-content-of-a-tab-while-switching/7226338#7226338)